# How can I type "å" on a non-Danish keyboard?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I usually have German and English keyboard layouts on Ubuntu 20.04, but I recently started writing in Danish as well, and I can write most special letters (e.g. "æ" via `AltGr-a`, "ø" via `AltGr-o` etc.). However, I can't figure out how to get an "å". I guess it should be `°a`, but the `°` isn't a dead key (unlike e.g. `^`, `´` etc.). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You can use a virtual keyboard of course, but it can be found in language specific extension of ascii table no ?   alt-gr + number  of the character (over 127)

Comment: See @terdon's answer below - it's Unicode now, i.e. `Ctrl-Shift-u` followed by `00e5`. But that's honestly a bit tedious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the English international with dead keys layout, and on my system I can get `å` with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (this combination is the dead key) and then <kbd>a</kbd>.

If that doesn't work for you for some reason, you can also enter the unicode code directly. First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to enter unicode mode, then write the relevant code, [`00e5` in this case](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e5/index.htm), and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Another option (suggested by [@vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium) in a comment) is to enable "compose key" in your keyboard settings. Then, you can use <kbd>compose key</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to get `å`. You can chose various keys as the "compose key".

Comment: Thanks, the second suggestion does work, although it's pretty tedious. The first suggestion results in a literal `°` being typed out, it's not a dead key on the German layout apparently. I guess I'll need to dive into Xmodmap and friends :-/

Comment: @FlorianEchtler also try some all possible keys. That's how I found that the AltGr+Shift+0  (that's zero, by the way, not the letter o) was a dead key for me: I just tried all the combinations of AltGr+Shift+key until I found one. So you probably have one as well.

Comment: The following xmodmap command does what I was looking for: `keycode 0x31 = dead_circumflex dead_abovering grave notsign U2032 U2033 bar bar` (it turns the non-dead degree symbol on the upper left key into a dead_abovering symbol which can then be composed with a, u, etc.)

Comment: @FlorianEchtler great! Please post that as an answer then, and accept it as soon as the system lets you, so the next person with a similar problem can find it.

Comment: I would add the possibility to set up a Compose key here. That linux only feature allows to enter foreign characters after hitting the Compose key. Compose followed by o a (or a o) will enter å. Enable a compose key under Keyboard settings.

Comment: @vanadium nice! On my system only compose+o+a works (not a+o), but yes indeed!

Comment: Where is the option to configure the Compose key? Can't seem to find it. Or what's the default on 20.04?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion with @terdon, I've figured out that I can use `xmodmap -e "keycode 0x31 = dead_circumflex dead_abovering grave notsign U2032 U2033 bar bar"` to turn the degree symbol on the upper-leftmost key into a dead key, i.e. I can now either type that key twice for a regular degree symbol, or type it once followed by "a" to get the letter "å" I was looking for all the time :-)

The original definition for the German keyboard is `dead_circumflex degree grave notsign U2032 U2033 bar bar`, so it's just changing `degree` to `dead_abovering` that does the trick.

Comment: `xmodmap` is not vary reliable anymore - switching keyboard layouts may stop it from working, for example.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Vanadium had a very good suggestion.

Comment: True, but I need to use xmodmap anyway for a non-standard laptop keyboard, so I'm sticking with that approach for now.